# why cookie is better to communicate with server?

Tags: javascript, cookies, server

My point is that why the cookie is better instead of a cookie we use local storage and session also but why many websites use a cookie for communicating or sending the information to the server

Answer (score 0):

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) are client level, you cannot read or modify these from the server. Cookies are added to the host which can be read by both. It is not about better, they have their own use cases. If you want to store something only on the client then you can use sessionStorage or localStorage. All these have different [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) criteria as well.

Also sessionStorage should not be confused with server sessions, which can only be handled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage**

localStorage is a way to store data on the client’s computer. It allows the saving of key/value pairs in a web browser and it stores data with no expiration date. localStorage can only be accessed via JavaScript, and HTML5.

**sessionStorage**

- stores data only for a session, meaning that the data is stored until
  the browser (or tab) is closed
- data is never transferred to the server
- can only be read on client-side
- storage limit is about 5-10MB

**Cookie**

- Stores data that has to be sent back to the server with subsequent XHR requests. Its expiration varies based on the type and the expiration duration can be set from either server-side or client-side
- Cookies are primarily for server-side reading (can also be read on client-side), localStorage and sessionStorage can only be read on client-side
- Cookies can be made secure by setting the httpOnly flag as true for that cookie. This prevents client-side access to that cookie

As you can see from the definitions, using any of the above has specific use case. Yes, most sites use `Cookie` for some specific tasks. But they also use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` for some other tasks as well. Nothing is best for all use cases.